# Identify this vertebra

Tags: species-identification, mammals, bone, vertebra

I was walking on the beach in New Jersey (U.S.), at about 40 degrees longitude, and found this bone. It's not a fish. The long process in the front is interesting. It is likely a C2 vertebra. I looked on the web, but could not find anything aquatic that it might match. Certainly not a dolphin. It is 2 inches long (50 mm), and 2.5 inches high and wide (64 mm). I guess it need not be aquatic, and New York City (20 miles North of here) used to dump garbage in the ocean. It looks old. Can you help me identify it?[image: Lateral][image: Dorsal][image: Posterior]

Comment: Looks very much like an axis (C2) vertebra. The give away is the odontoid process (aka "dens") clearly visible on the bottom of each photo. Spinous process looks uniquely shaped (keel like) which might help your search. Size sounds too large for dog/cat, but who knows. Definitely not human.

Comment: [www.boneid.net](http://www.boneid.net/search) provides a great searchable database of identified bones

Comment: I found a picture with various cow vertebrae here: https://www.chichesterinc.com/Images2012/1172-40-V1-Lg.jpg Not sure your's is there.

Comment: Still disappointed that I can't figure out what this is. Is it pretty difficult to identify a single vertebra?

Comment: By the size you said and using the bonid site mentioned, it can looks also like a [wild boar C2](http://www.boneid.net/product/wild-boar-sus-scrofa-c2-superior-view/). But do you have wild boar in NJ?

Answer (score -2):

[image: Kjer, This image can give you more idea]

Looks like Lumbar Vertebrae or Sacral Vertebrae of a Cow like @Brian Hanson Said above.

Studying closely in laboratory can elaborate more secrets about the bones.

Comment: This is not a lumbar or sacral vertebra. It doesn't even look like it's from a cow: http://www.boneid.net/product/lateral-view-cattle-c2-vertebrae/